# assign scores to items which have been placed in a ranking order

Tags: sql, statistics, ranking

Consider five choices of ice cream: vanilla, chocolate, raspberry, strawberry, mango.

People are asked to rank their preferences for flavour. They can rank one or more of the flavours. So some people may rank all five, some may rank only one or two.

The problem is to produce a final ranking of flavours across all the data.

One method is to assign 5 points for position 1 down to 1 point for a position 5. You can then either calculate the average score or use the total score.

However each has its own problems.

Calculating the average means that five people ranking mango fifth has the same weight as one person ranking it first (5*1==1*5).

An alternative is to compare, for each person, the difference in positions between the flavours that have been ranked and assign plus and minus scores based on the position difference.

So someone whose ranking order was chocolate, mango, strawberry would produce:
chocolate v mango=chocolate+1, mango-1
chocolate v strawberry would give chocolate+2, strawberry-2
mango v strawberry would give mango+1, strawberry-1

Result after this one person: chocolate:3, mango:0, strawberry:-3

Then accumulate the scores for each flavour across all the data.

But is there a standard statistical way of doing this?

Comment: Are the sql and asp tags necessary?

Comment: This seems to be more about the statistical model rather than the implementation, have you considered asking in: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must they be in a ranked order? Someone may like 2 flavours equally/have no preference, but like them both strongly.

A score for each option would be another approach, that could capture this and solve the problems you mentioned. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_Promoter may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is large body of work on this problem. It is generally referred to as [social choice theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_choice_theory). The basic problem is to take the preferences of several individuals and try to aggregate them into preference for the group.

The short answer is that the theory side is a gigantic [mess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) with no clear solution emerging. I think your points system is the way to go on the basis of simplicity and transparency.

The big problem with doing a ranking of items relative to each other is that you don't know the distance between them. One person might have the slightest preference for chocolate over vanilla while another might have a very strong preference. Without knowing the magnitude of how much happiness each item brings to the user constructing an aggregate ranking is very hard. Also, it is possible to get paradox's where the aggregate measure prefers item A to B, B to C and C to A.

An alternative is to ask people how much would you pay for a cone of each flavor of ice cream. The situation becomes much easier for you, but harder for the user.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_Pairs seems to be a good method. I'd not thought about this being similar to a multiple candidate, multiple seat voting system.

Comment: I believe the ranked Paris method would be equivalent to giving 4 points to the first place, 3 for second, 2 for third and 1 for 4th. This is pretty much your points system with slightly different weights. While ice cream probably isn't worth a lot of thought, social choice theory gets more onerous in that, once you publish how you will determine a winner from the responses, that users will have a systematic incentive to misrepresent their actual preferences to achieve their desired end. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbard%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to average the rankings for an item and only show those with at least a minimum number of votes.